# How to send variable(mongodb doc id) from one async function to other async function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await

I've two async functions, which are `async function start(){}` & `async function end(){}`
So in both functions I'm having mongodb operations. I want to send document id generated inside start() function to the end() function and then log it there.
This is my start function:

```
async function start() {    
      await client.connect();
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      const col = db.collection("mongotroncol");
      let personDocument = {
        "name" : "shubham"
      }
       // Insert a single document, wait for promise so we can read it back
       const p = await col.insertOne(personDocument);
       const abc = p.insertedId;
       const docid = abc.toString()
       return docid;
  }
```

and then I've this end() function and I'm trying to send unique docid generated in start() function to the end() function with returning that value & log it in end() function as follows:

```
async function end() {
      mongoid = await start();
      console.log(mongoid);
}
```

So for example "623cb515366c70a2a3c27288" this is my document id generated in start() function then what I desire is to console.log this same id in end() function but as I'm writing `await start()` in end() function, again start() function is called & run, result of which new mongodb document id is generated and new one is logged but I want the doc id generated from start() only.

**One important point:
I've two events which are app.on('ready') & app.on('quit') so I'm calling await start() & await end() respectively like this:**

```
app.on('ready', () => {
await start();
});
```

and

```
app.on('quit', () => {
await end();
});
```

So my 1st button click will trigger app.on('ready') event which will run async start() function and generate a mongodb document with unique docid and then on my 2nd button click(which I'll do after some minutes) will trigger app.on('quit') which will run async end() function & ideally I want the same docid generated in async start() function but I'm getting "623cb515366c70a2a3c27289" which is exactly one bit incremented than the generated in start() function [please see the id value mentioned in the earlier paragraph]
So the concern is to get same docid.
Thank you!!

Comment: What is `app`? What should happen if the `quit` event fires before a `ready` event? What should happen if there are multiple `ready` events and multiple `quit` events? Can they overlap? What if their numbers don't match?

Comment: @Bergi this is an electron app, please find code here https://github.com/shubham2924/electron-authentication-app/blob/main/frontend/main.js
There should only one ready and only one quit event, ready event is triggered when app is opened & quit is triggered when you close the app and I want id to be same as I want to get difference b/w desktop app open time and when the app is closed

Comment: In that case, just store the value in a (global) variable shared between the `ready` and `quit` handlers.

Comment: @Bergi could you please elaborate this through a code?

Comment: Really just `var mongoid; app.on('ready', () => { mongoid = await start(); }); app.on('quit', () => { await end(mongoid); });`

Comment: @Bergi I followed your approach but when I wrote end(mongoid); i.e as said by you passing mongoid as a parameter to the end() function, I got the error of Uncaught Exception ReferenceError : mongoid is not defined         so I think this way it's not becoming global to use it in other function

Comment: It is. You either didn't put the `var` or the `app.on` call in the right scope, or you didn't modify `end` to actually take it as a parameter.

Comment: @Bergi I've added the complete file code to codesandbox, please find it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/e081i3), will you please edit this code the way you want to tell?

Comment: There's an unrelated "*await' is only allowed within async functions*" error, and you called the variable `mymongoid` in on place and `mongoid` in the other.

Comment: Hello @Bergi I've added the solution below & issue has been resolved, thanks a lot for your time & inputs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit brainstorming I tried one approach & it worked.

- I declared a global variable as `let doc_id = "";`
- Then in `start()` function I just assigned a value to `doc_id` like this:

  ```
  async function start() {    
     await client.connect();

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  const col = db.collection("mongotroncol");

  let personDocument = {
      "name" : "shubham"
  }

  const p = await col.insertOne(personDocument);

  doc_id = p.insertedId.toString();
  ```

  }
- And now at the time of calling the `end()` function I did this:

```js
app.on('quit', () => {
    await end(doc_id);
});
```

- And at last passed this id as a parameter to the function:

```js
async function end(doc_id) {
    console.log(doc-id);
}
```